# content_tag not working in a rails 4.2.10 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I'm having trouble with this simple helper.

```
  def green_title(&block)
    content_tag(:h3) do
      concat block.call
    end
  end
```

called with:

```
  <% green_title do %>
    stuff for the title
  <% end %>
```

the problem is that it only renders `stuff for the title`, the h3 tag is missing.

Probably worth saying that this template is rendered in a service via `ERB.new(template).result(binding)`, and I had to include  `include ActionView::Helpers` in the service in order to have the helpers I needed

I tried doing so:

```
  def green_title(&block)
    content_tag(:h3) do
      block.call
    end
  end
```

and using it via

```
  <%= green_title do %>
    stuff for the title
  <% end %>
```

but this gets me a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected ')'
...rbout.concat(( green_title do ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n   ...
...                               ^
(erb):4254: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
                                      ^:
  (erb):1649:in `'
```

Comment: You have to add the `=` to the `green_title` ERB brackets (`<%= green_title do %>`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but got a syntax error, I updated the question with the details

Comment: In what file are you calling the method? Is that a string what you're passing in the block?

Comment: I'm calling the helper in a `html.erb` that is rendered in a service via `Erb.new`, in the block atm I'm passing just a string, but I'll need to pass in a bit more complex stuff, once I figure this one out